# How can I send the right tenant id to Azure AD for user authorization when a user clicks on my app from the marketplace?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I have created a multi-tenant app in Azure. I have a web application where each company has a different subdomain [myclient].webapp.com. For the callback, I have an id_token and using the tenant (Directory) Id I can look up what company it is and redirect them to the right subdomain. Now that I am trying to setup the app in the market place, the only thing I can see to set is a single value "Home page URL" in the branding section of my Azure app. I am trying to figure out a way know what subdomain to send them to (since it appears that I can only set one value for the Home page URL and not have separate values for separate companies. If there was a way to get the tenantId I could look it up and redirect them to the right subdomain.

Potential solutions:

**Option 1**

I could have the home page url set to an html page that informs them to go to their company specific url, but that doesn't seem like the best user experience coming from the marketplace.

**Option 2**

I could have the home page url set to an html page that asks them what their company email address is and then based on that I look up the correct tenantId, but what happens if their work email doesn't match the domain setup in the Azure AD account?

**Option 3**

I could have the home page url set to an html page that provides a dropdown where the user selects what company they work for, but then all our customers can see which of our customers have sso setup not to mention them having to sift through all our clients to find their own company and select the right one.

Are there any other options that I am not aware of? Is there any way to get the tenant id in a more automated way without user input? Since the myapps.microsoft.com portal knows what tenant the user is logged in as, it seems like I should be able to get that somehow rather than putting that burden on the user. Hopefully I am just missing something obvious. Thanks in advance for any help or direction on this. Hopefully I included all the needed details. If not, feel free to tell me what information I need to add.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on Azure market place but it feels like these are the main concepts. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding.

**TENANT ID**

This is a 'claim' value that is only available after login, where it is provided in tokens.

**GENERIC HOME PAGE**

It feels like you need some kind of generic home page that could operate in 2 modes, perhaps based on some context in local storage:

- When user is signed in show a customised experience based on who they are
- When user is not signed in you render a Sign In button, the result of which will set the above context

**USER CHOICES**

Totally agree that the user should not need to choose anything. The only thing they should ever have to do is sign in.

Comment: Gary you beat me by 55 secs XD

Comment: No probs Alfredo - looks like we're saying roughly the same thing :)

Comment: The tenant id in the active directory world is the "Active Directory ID". The generic home page would work fine if I didn't have to support SP initiated SSO. I can tell what company it is because the user company specific subdomains mycustomer.mywebapp.com. Does that make sense. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

What about addding Azure AD authenticantion to the Home Page URL? Once logged in you can use [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list) and your own business logic to list the tenants available to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason I need to know the tenantId before the login is because I need to know whether or not this company has SSO enabled. If they do and they hit there company specific subdomain companyspecific.mywebapp.com I do SP initiatied SSO and they will be prompted to sign in via Azure. If they don't have it enabled the will be taken to our login screen to login in with credentials managed by us. Let me know if any of that is unclear.

Comment: So is there something in the URL that you can map to a tenant id in that case, to take the user to the right login system? Eg an idp parameter?

Comment: @testing123 just to be sure I'm on the same page as you: you want users to visit the home page and from there be redirected to your webapp trough a per customer subdomain to then be able to initiate a login to AAD. is that correct?

Comment: @AlfredoR.-MSFTIdentity the idea was to be able to get to the app from the "gallery" but I don't think that is possible. I think I was thinking about this wrong. I think what needs to happen is the company that wants it will need to setup the app on their side.